# When a friend sends me link it sometimes doesn't work like in his computer?

Tags: http, url, webserver, httprequest, httpresponse

I read somewhere that it's because the URL doesn't contain the body of the HTTP request.

Is it true? If so, can someone please explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, basically that's right.

First and foremost, HTTP may use different request methods (or verbs) in order to request a resource at the given location.

By default, when seeing an URL like "https://stackoverflow.com/", a browser requests this page using a simple HTTP `GET`.

Other verbs are `POST`, `DELETE`, `PUT` and so on. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods.

Furthermore, HTTP requests may contain different headers, such as [referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) and [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

Lastly, the a HTTP request may contain data in the body of the request.

Getting the same response from a web server when sending two requests would indeed require all of the different parts of the request to be the same.

A simple URL just does not contain any of the extra information required to be sent and that's the reason why you get a different response for the same URL on different computers.